# Excel formula which can write specific column on the basis of colors in column Q,V,W,X,Y,Z

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one excel file, which may or may not contain colours in column Q,v,w,x,y,z. if any of these column contain colour I need to write "Yes" else "No" in "Colour" column, could someone help me here please?

formula by which I can achieve this.

Comment: Are the colours the result of Conditional Formatting?

Comment: The resaon @JosWoolley asks is because you can't use the color as an argument in any of the excel formulas. However, you can use the same formula you have in the conditional formatting to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Yes, the colour are result of conditional formatting, there are over 300 words which are used for conditional formatting. Thank you for suggestions

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the result???

Answer (score 0):

That could be achieved by creating a Macro, here is an example:

```
Sub YesMacro()
'
' Macro to write "Yes" if there is a fill color and "No" otherwise
' Applied to a selected range
'
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Selection
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If (c.Interior.Color <> 16777215) Then
            c.FormulaR1C1 = "Yes"
        Else
            c.FormulaR1C1 = "No"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```